# Столкнулся с проблемой при проверке на ввод EOF. Либо возникает ошибка сегментирования, либо break не срабатывает для счетчика

Tags: c

Программа некорректно работает в структурах с проверкой на EOF. Если делаю через структуру do...while возникает "ошибка  сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)", если иду через цикл for (в коде снизу он закомментирован), то для счетчика цикла не срабатывает оператор break (то есть ввод прекращается. При выводе элементов массива, до которых ввод не дошел - выводится значение инициализированное по умолчанию, но значение i выводится как 21). В чем ошибка?

То, что EOF прекращает ввод - условие задания.

Подкорректированный код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

double rootCalc(const double, const double, const double);

main ()
{
   double mass[SIZE]={0};
   double e, x0=1, x;
   int i=0, max;
   
   printf("Please enter 'e' value: ");
   scanf("%lf", &e);
   
   FILE *input;
   input=fopen("input", "r");
   printf("\nPlease enter value of xi (enter EOF character to end input):\n");
   for (i=0; i<21;) {
      if (fscanf(input, "%lf", &mass[i]))
         i++;
      else
         break;
   }
   
   max=i;
   
   printf("\nRoots calculation\n");
   //printf("%10s  %10s\n", "Value", "Root");
   for (i=0; i<max; i++) {
      x=mass[i];
      x=rootCalc(x, e, x0);
      printf("%-.10g  %-.10g\n", mass[i], x);
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do {
   i++;
   scanf("%lf", &mass[0][i]);
}
while (mass[0][i] != (EOF));
```

Однако...

Кто вам сказал, что при невозможности чтения в переменной окажется -1?

```
while(scanf("%lf", &mass[0][i]) == 1) ++i;
```

P.S. Кстати, на всякий случай — что вы имеете в виду, когда пишете

```
enter EOF character to end input
```

Что именно и как именно должен ввести пользователь?

P.P.S. Вы преднамеренно начинаете считывание с элемента `mas[0][1]`? Так и надо?

Comment: В задании сказано, что ввод прекращается при вводе EOF (end of file) - комбинация ctrl+d.

Comment: Тогда все написанное мною остается в силе... Сейчас у вас для окончания ввода надо ввести `-1`. Именно это значение имеет `EOF`. Единственное - не знаю, как именно в linux отработает Ctrl+d, закроет ли поток ввода при вводе не из файла, а с консоли.

Comment: В структуре do...while пока да, считывается с элемента mass[0][1] (структуру do...while я добавил как проверку, так как не получилось с циклом for (i продолжает суммироваться до 21, а мне нужно, чтобы он при вводе EOF прекратил ввод и подсчет (поэтому там break поставил) - но ввод прекращается (причем ошибки сегментирования никакой не возникает), а счетчик продолжается суммироваться до 21.

Comment: -1 я вводил - он на него вообще никак не среагировал, просто предлагает продолжить ввод (это касается цикла for). В структуре do...while сейчас попробовал сработало.

Comment: После перезагрузки VBox цикл for тоже сработал со значением -1 (i суммируется корректно, ввод останавливается). Но с комбинацией ctrl+d та же проблема осталась - ввод останавливается, но счетчик доходит до 21. (добавил скриншот с этой проблемой)

Comment: С Ctrl+d у вас просто ничего не считывается (идет ошибка), вот цикл и проскакивает до 21... Попробуйте свой `if` записать так: `if (scanf("%lf", &mass[0][i])) i++; else break;`

Comment: попробовал через структуру while (i<SIZE) с таким if в его теле - счетчик все равно уходит "до конца".

Comment: Проверьте, как работает перенаправление из файла, в который запишите то, что вводите руками (кроме Ctrl+d, понятно). Если отработает верно - значит, Ctrl+d в linux не закрывает поток ввода. Тут я пас, в linux я по нулям. Если с ошибкой - значит, неверно переписали код.

Comment: Вроде код правильно переписал (выше вывесил обновленный. Данные идут из файла), но счетчик все равно улетает до предельного значения - 17 последнее значение в файле.

Comment: Да, я неверно переписал — попробуйте `if (fscanf(input, "%lf", &mass[i]) == 1)`, проверка, что считано именно одно значение. Он может возвращать и ненулевое значение при ошибке, EOF.

Comment: Да, так получилось. Спасибо огромное! Я правильно понял, что корректность достигнута за счет того, что условный оператор if получает значение true (1) только если вводятся числа. А если встречается что-то что не имеет числового представления, то там будет значение false =>  происходит выход из цикла?

Comment: Да, если вводится одно число. При вводе, например, строки или при завершении файла возвращается 0 или EOF. Да, и спасибо здесь принимает форму принятого ответа (птичка слева).